# aws lambda return json data with slashes

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

i need to print a json data using aws lambda. this is my code

```
'use strict';
console.log('Loading function');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

  var addon = require('./path/to/addon');
  var sampleData=addon.getSampleData(userId);
  console.log(sampleData); // it will print correct json data
  //var sampleData="{ \"data\":{ \"key1\": \"1472722877992\", \"key2\": [ 814, 809] }}";

   callback(null, sampleData);
};
```

i got output like this

```
"{ \"data\":{ \"key1\": \"1472722877992\", \"key2\": [ 814, 809] }}"
```

Bu  i need to get output like this

```
"{ "data":{ "key1": "1472722877992", "key2": [ 814, 809] }}"
```

in this code, i created a npm library  ***addon*** using c++ code.  and ***getSampleData*** is a method inside c++ code. it will return a json formated string(not a json object) .in my node.js code, console log print 
correct json string.

But executing this lambda function returnd output with Slashes. How to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"{ "data":{ "key1": "1472722877992", "key2": [ 814, 809] }}"` isn't a valid string. It's a double quoted string with non-escaped double quotes embedded in it. That isn't valid.

Have you tried using single quotes for the string, like this?

`var sampleData='{ "data":{ "key1": "1472722877992", "key2": [ 814, 809] }}';`

Or have you tried just returning a JSON object like this?

`var sampleData={ "data":{ "key1": "1472722877992", "key2": [ 814, 809] }};`

---

**Edit based on new info in question:**

Try converting the string to a JSON object like this:

`callback(null, JSON.parse(sampleData));`

Comment: thanks mark, but in my case, i got json formated  string from a method. console.log print correct data. but result is wrong. Question updated

Comment: I was moving from AWS-EC2 to serverless and faced this,  JSON.parse(sampleData) did the trick

Comment: I am facing the backlashes problem on the other end after calling a Lambda function with the AWS CLI. Using JSON.stringify(orders) works - no backslashes in the when testing with console.log(orders).
orders is a JS object that looks like this:

{
    "id": "1",
    "uid": "gsmith",
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "HFS - Lightweight Road Running",
            "single_price": "105.20",
            "currency": "USD",
            "count": "2"
        }
    ],
    "order_total": "210.40"
}
,
{
    "id": "2",...
}
]